# Why enzyme gives "Failed prop type" on a decorated child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, decorator, enzyme

If I use a Higher-Order Component (HOC) as a decorator, i.e.,

```
@withStyles({})
class Bar extends React.Component { ... }
```

I'd get this error with enzyme:

```
  console.error node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:19
    Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `classes` is marked as required in `_class`, but its value is `undefined`.
        in _class
```

If I use the function form, i.e.,

```
const Bar = withStyles({})(class extends React.Component { ... });
```

there are no errors.

Why?

Note that this warning only happens on a child component; see the code from reproduction steps for what I mean.

### Reproduction steps

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^23.3.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-class-properties",
      "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

`__tests__/app.test.js`:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const withStyles = styles => Component => class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Component classes={styles} />
  }
}

// This will produce a failed prop type warning:
@withStyles({})
class Bar extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}

// This will NOT produce a failed prop type warning:
// const Bar = withStyles({})(class extends React.Component {
  // static propTypes = {
    // classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  // }

  // render() {
    // return <div>test</div>;
  // }
// });

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Bar />;
  }
}

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<Test />);
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Run `npm t`

There are two code blocks: one with decoration and the other (currently commented out) with function form. Simply comment out the decorator block and uncomment the function form block to test both cases.

This problem originally arose when using material-ui and I can confirm that both cases render the same UI visually. This prevented me from using the decorator form of `withStyles`.

Note that there are some more investigations by me here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` needs come before `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, i.e., in the `package.json`:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "transform-class-properties"
    ],
```